# Synchronize default applications between Ubuntu installations

Tags: default-programs

I want to find a way to synchronize the default application preferences for Ubuntu between multiple installations. For example, if I choose Geany as the default text editor for .js files, I want it to become the default text editor for all of my Ubuntu installations. Is there any software that makes this possible, or software libraries that I could use to implement such a feature?

Comment: Also, the "sync" and "synchronize" tags on AskUbuntu ought to be merged.

Comment: Here's a relevant Google search: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ubuntu+transfer+desktop+settings&oq=ubuntu+transfer+des&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i30j0i8i30.486.5937.1.6864.21.17.2.2.2.1.273.1826.10j5j2.17.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.86Z54TA0Z7c&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=52e43fe95f7f41ff&bpcl=35466521&biw=1301&bih=656

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu used to have a tool called Migration Assistant, but it appears that it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any automated way but you can always go ahead and copy the `mimeapps.list` file located at `~/.local/share/applications` between your installations. That way all your custom file type associations should be transferred safely.

Comment: This is a relevant question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152291/synchronize-applications-between-computers-automatically

Comment: Is it likely that OneConf will eventually fill this role?

Comment: Where is the `~/.local/share/applications` located within the filesystem?

Comment: That's the full directory path. `~/.local/share/applications` stands for `/home/username/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Oh, and sorry, I don't know anything about Oneconf.